# Is there a way to programmatically stop web.py?

Tags: python, web.py

I'm trying to run web.application in a Windows Service and I cannot find a way to programmatically stop it after application.run().

I tried sys.exit and it didn't work well with Windows Service.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the question I originally raised by looking into web.py source code, and exposed the WSGIServer in web/httpserver.py to web/application.py, so that i can call WSGIServer.stop() in application.stop(), which is added by myself.

It's a quick hack and not that neat, but it removed the blocker quickly.